# Sum to Infinity-

Tags: sequences-and-series, nested-radicals

What is the sum of this infinite series $\sqrt{1+ \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{3 + \sqrt{4 + \sqrt{5 + \ldots }}}}}$?

I couldn't find the logic to solve the question.
Please provide me a logic to begin with..

*I don't want its full answer as I want to try it doing myself...*

I have asked this question on [QUORA](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-sum-of-this-infinite-series-%E2%88%9A-1+%E2%88%9A-2+%E2%88%9A-3+%E2%88%9A-4+%E2%88%9A-5) but haven't got any answer yet..

Comment: Read this a [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Very interesting question... You could try making a recurrence relation which has terms $a_1=1, a_2=\sqrt [2] {1+\sqrt [2] {2}}$, and so on. This may not work though.

Comment: [Related OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A072449)

Comment: Not really an infinite series.

Comment: This seems related to Ramanujan's evaluation of:$$\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+\dotsb}}}$$which equals $3$(!)

Comment: I think that's proven by showing that it's equal to the limit of $3$, $\sqrt{1+2(4)}$, $\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3(5)}}$, … $\sqrt{1+\dotsb+(n-1)\sqrt{1+n(n+2)}}$, …, which is the constant sequence.